# How to write a file as root in a program that is not run as root?

Tags: file, io, racket, root, sudo

I have a program that should not be ran as root because it does things based on the name of the user among other things. However, there is a possibility that I would need to write a file that is (and should be) just writable as root.

What I could do, but would rather not, is write the file to some temporary file, and then `(system "sudo mv /tmp/myfile /destination/myfile")`. That would have sudo ask for the password, move the file as root, and then the program would keep running as a normal user. If the user cannot `sudo` he should not be using the program so that doesn't really matter.

I would like to just be able to write the file from the program without having temporary files though, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executables (this is how `sudo` or `su` or `login` works). Read [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html),  [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html). Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

But  be careful. You can introduce security holes or [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)).

BTW, `sudo` (or `super`) could be configured to avoid asking any password (but doing that might be unwise).